# How to run two function from same resource(plot graphic and saving infinite data to txt file)

Tags: python, multithreading, serial-port, wxpython, pyserial

I'm new in Python, try to develop gui app. My data source is from serial port. When i pressed buttons, it should plot graphics and print it on the screen and print to new txt file.

All of above that i mentioned should do separetely.

**My expected is:** How can i run both saving data and plotting many graphics concurrently from same resource

I used threading, time.sleep, wx.Timer. but I couldn't succeed on it. Anybody can help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide your code so that users can help you , see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask how to ask good questions.

Comment: When reading from a serial port the data is effectively consumed by that process. That process will have to plot `and` write to the text file or plot and store or pass on data for another process to write the text file. You cannot have 2 processes reading the same data from the serial port.

Comment: i also did what you said: (1)store(from serial port) to a list, (2)plot stored data, and (3)write to txt&delete with three wxTimer. But it freezes while plotting with matplotlib after 2 min. When i extend recursion limit to max, it last just 6 min then everything shot down without given any error. However Newville's suggestion different plot type which is wxmplot works. I didnt understand why matplotlib freeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly use a wx.Timer event to fetch the latest data from the serial port.  With that data, you can stream it to an open file and update a graph of the data.

Without a more detailed question, it's hard to give a detailed answer.  But, you may find the wxmplot library (https://newville.github.io/wxmplot/) useful.  In fairness, I am the lead author of that library.  One of its features I use it for  is very similar to your need: "live updated plots" of data from an external source, and without recreating a new matplotlib figure for each new data set.

You might find the example at https://github.com/newville/wxmplot/blob/master/examples/stripchart.py to be a useful example.  It has a function that simulates data, but you can replace this with "read from serial port" or fetching other data sources.

Comment: that is a separate question and a longer topic.  A wx.Timer is good enough if the data comes predictably and quickly, as is the case for the example I linked to.  You may want to use threads or other mechanisms if i/o is slow, which it might be for data from a serial port.  I'd recommend starting with just wx.Timer and see if it is good enough.

Comment: The data comes every second. I skipped that problem and now i stuck with new one. The problem is my program run for 2 minutes then it give 'stack overflow' error. I append my infinite data to list and delete it after plotting, using wx.Timer. I dont know why it gave that error.

Comment: as earlier, that is a completely different question.  It cannot be addressed in comments to an answer.  If data comes every second, you should not fill memory in two minutes.  Please post a complete example and the complete traceback you get as a separate question.